# Radeon driver segfault in X.org

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, amd-graphics, radeon

I have a Dell R720 home lab configured with a `AMD Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R5 430 OEM R7 240/340 Radeon 520 OEM]` GPU. This is an old GCN 1 card, so I decided to use the `radeon` driver instead of the open-source `amdgpu` driver, since the latter only has [experimental](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg#AMD) support for GCN 1 cards (or maybe the support has matured in 2024 and I should switch to `amdgpu`? let me know if that's the case). I want to run a desktop environment on the AMD card. The system has a few other Nvidia cards that I intend to use as computing cards (so X.org should not run on them).

I attempted to configure X.org to use the `radeon` driver with the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` posted at the bottom, but the screen froze at the Ubuntu loading screen as I reboot the machine. Here is the [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/96Wi59jR) for the error message in `~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`. There is a segfault caused by the `radeon` driver. Additionally, [here](https://pastebin.com/cag8buZQ) is the output of `dmesg`. It contains suspicious messages like `UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-hwe-6.5-ZV1Qen/linux-hwe-6.5-6.5.0/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_atombios.c:2717:34`

How do I fix the issue? Should I switch to `amdgpu` or stay on `radeon`? Which of them are more actively maintained?

```
$ uname -a
Linux mjollnir 6.5.0-18-generic #18~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Feb  7 11:40:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsmod | grep -E 'radeon|amdgpu'
radeon               2170880  7
drm_suballoc_helper    16384  1 radeon
drm_ttm_helper         12288  1 radeon
ttm                   110592  2 radeon,drm_ttm_helper
drm_display_helper    241664  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper        270336  6 drm_display_helper,mgag200,radeon,nvidia_drm
drm                   761856  18 drm_kms_helper,drm_suballoc_helper,drm_shmem_helper,drm_display_helper,nvidia,mgag200,radeon,drm_ttm_helper,nvidia_drm,ttm
video                  73728  2 radeon,nvidia_modeset
i2c_algo_bit           16384  3 igb,mgag200,radeon

$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102GL [Tesla P40] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GP102GL [Tesla P40]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
--
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. G200eR2
        DeviceName: Embedded Video
        Subsystem: Dell G200eR2
        Kernel driver in use: mgag200
--
42:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102GL [Tesla P40] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GP102GL [Tesla P40]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
43:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R5 430 OEM / R7 240/340 / Radeon 520 OEM] (rev 87)
        Subsystem: Dell Radeon R5 430 OEM (2048 MByte)
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
        Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
--
44:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

$ inxi -G --display
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP102GL [Tesla P40] driver: nvidia v: 470.223.02
  Device-2: Matrox Systems G200eR2 driver: mgag200 v: kernel
  Device-3: NVIDIA GP102GL [Tesla P40] driver: nvidia v: 470.223.02
  Device-4: AMD Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R5 430 OEM R7 240/340 Radeon 520 OEM] driver: radeon
    v: kernel
  Device-5: NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 710] driver: nvidia v: 470.223.02
  Display: server: X.org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: radeon gpu: radeon
    resolution: 1920x1200
  Message: No GL data found on this system.

$ apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri
libgl1-mesa-dri:
  Installed: 24.0.0~kisak2~j
  Candidate: 24.0.0~kisak2~j
  Version table:
     24.0.0~rc3+git2401302259.6dadb9b032c~j~mesarc4 1
          1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ernstp/mesarc/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
 *** 24.0.0~kisak2~j 500
        500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-proposed/main amd64 Packages
     23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     22.0.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Content in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "AutoAddGPU" "off"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Radeon"
    Driver         "radeon"
    BusID          "PCI:67:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Radeon"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: That is the radeonsi mesa userspace, not the radeon kernel driver. Try updating mesa by adding the https://launchpad.net/~kisak/+archive/ubuntu/kisak-mesa PPA

Comment: @DanielT OK, I have added the PPA. Which specific packages should I install? `sudo apt install mesa` gives me `E: Unable to locate package mesa`.

Comment: You don't need to `apt install` because it replaces packages from default packages. Just update and upgrade

Comment: Done, but `sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade` gives `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.`

Comment: What do you get for `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri`?

Comment: @DanielT It's too long to be included in a comment. See the updated the post.

Comment: @DanielT It's hidden at the bottom of the code block starting with `uname -a`. You need to scroll down a bit to see it (or visit this [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/DiE1Ug0p))

Comment: You are mixing mesa versions. You have ernstp/mesarc previously installed as well. This is likely to break things, and I'm not sure that "Almost Stable"'s "Release candidates" are reliable. Please either reinstall all mesa packages, or reinstall Ubuntu after ensuring that the new repository is the only one. There are also a bunch of "scsi/mpt3sas" errors in your dmesg, so there are two problems happening at once. You might as well try out the `amdgpu` driver to see if it fixes your X11, worst case you can switch back if there any problems

Comment: @DanielT Reinstalling Ubuntu would be too much trouble, but I can surely reinstall all mesa packages. What's the appropriate to do that, `sudo apt-get remove --purge "*mesa*"` followed by `sudo apt install mesa`?

Comment: I don't know how to safely uninstall just mesa. `sudo apt install mesa` doesn't exist. `sudo apt-get remove --purge "*mesa*"` will likely try to uninstall unrelated packages such as your `ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Well, this is tough. I don't mind losing `ubuntu-desktop` since I have SSH access anyway. Maybe I should do a `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mesa-va-drivers` as suggested by [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/uibtjt/how_to_install_mesa_drivers_on_ubuntu_2204_lts/)...